# How to remove the stock status in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I need to remove the stock status for particular product type in admin product form.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, donot understand what you means by remove the stock status

Comment: I need to remove the stock status attribute for some product type in product form

Comment: From admin  or frontend?

Comment: Admin end .....

Comment: Just remove quantity_and_stock_status attribute from attribute set, or you can new Attribute Set and remove it. which prodct type you much assign to the attribute set have no quantity_and_stock_status attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove This attribute from Products.Just goto **Advance Inventory** Section and make `Manage Stock To`No`.

[image]

Comment: It removed the stock status for all product types ... But  i need to remove it  only for custom product type.

Comment: You can do for the specific products also just  make   checkbox = trick and select 'No`

Comment: If i select no the stock status attribute remove for all product types.. How to do this for specific product

Comment: If you make manage stock to No then   Stock Status attribute will be remove from that product\

Comment: Yes.. i have created custom product type like Simple product type and i need to remove this attribute for all products under custom product type

Comment: I need to remove it not only for product .... for whole product type

Comment: You don't understand my point

Answer (score 0):

For remove the stock status attribute for specific product type

```
 $meta['product-details']['children']['container_quantity_and_stock_status']['children']['quantity_and_stock_status']['arguments']['data']['config'] = [
            'componentType' => 'container',
            'label' => __('Stock Status'),
            'visible' => false,
        ];
```